# ESLint configuration error at WebStorm (React project)

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have an issue while connecting ESLint airbnb configuration to my React App.
I have already tried to remove package-lock.json, node_modules and run a command

> npm install

WebStorm says

```
ESLint: Error: .eslintrc.json >> eslint-config-airbnb-base >> MyApplicationPath\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb-base\rules\imports.js
```

My package.json has only 1 devDependency

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you run `eslint app`?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `webstorm` is an appropriate tag here unless this only happens when you run `npm install` in webstorm and does not happen outside webstorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the peerDependencies? `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-import`

[eslint-config-airbnb-base](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base#eslint-config-airbnb-base-1)